Nikkud of מפעילה + אותו
What is the proper nikkud of the feminine הפעיל in the present tense, + אותו? (E.g. מַחֲזִירָה + אוֺתוֺ.) I’ve seen it vowelized variously as ,מַחֲזִירְתּוֺ, מַחֲזִירַתּוּ and מַחֲזִירָתוֺ. (I’ve noticed the Kehati Mishnayos vowelizes pi’el in the present tense as מְשַׁמְרַתּוּ, although I had assumed this was an error.)
Does anyone know of any examples in Tanach where this form appears?

According to the Hebrew Academy seems your last two options are both legitimate in Modern Hebrew https://hebrew-academy.org.il/meeting/%d7%a9%d7%a2%d7%95/

It doesn't appear in Tanakh. Only 30 cases of f.sg. hifil participles occur, and none have a suffix.

@magicker72 Is the reason for this simply the lack of occasion to use that form? Or does this tell us something about the rules of biblical grammar?

@Yø-cRo Probably lack of occasion. There are only 30 f.sg. hifil participles in Tanakh. There are 26 f.sg. participles with suffix pronouns, but none are hifil.

All of them are okay. The difference between cases 2 and 3 is probably if the word is in pause, if it's in pause then the shva probably turns into a qamets. The 1st case is also okay, it is just that the long form מַחֲזִירַתְהוּ, when the suffix gets swallowed up in the תּ it becomes מַחֲזִירַתּוּ, hence the dagesh for compensation.
It works the same way like in past verbs, the form זכרה becomes the form זְכָרַתְהוּ with a suffix  (she remembered him) and  then to זְכָרַתּוּ when the ה  gets swallowed up in the תּ. The same happens to זְכָרַתְהָ (she remembered her), this always becomes זְכָרַתָּה, and always without mappik.
I don't think I could find sources for the present tense because even the past tense is hard to find, but they should both work the way way.
ישעיהו 59:16 זְכָרַתְהוּ
רות 4:15 זְכָרַתּוּ
ישעיהו 34:17 זְכָרַתָּה

Hi, thanks for your response. The theory seems to work, but being that the laws of grammar are based on practical usage and not vice versa, I would like to see this form used in practice.

@Yø-cRo phonetically the vowels work the same way on object suffixes, especially if you found the piel present already, the hiphil would work the same

My question wasn’t specifically piel vs hifil; it was past tense vs present, something I’ve never seen in tanach.

@Yø-cRo just like in past and future tense there's no difference in object suffixes between kal-hitpael, the same is with the present. Suffixes work  basically in a predictable way, no matter if Kal or piel, as long as they are in the same tense, and even in different tenses there are only minor differences like if the helping vowel in a qamets or tzere.
